# How to use FormControl.valueChanges to format input value

Tags: angular, angular8

I want to format every value entered into a certain `FormControl` on my page using `parseFloat`, due to a requirement from a third party plugin, so I made something like:

```
this.form.get('latitude').valueChanges.subscribe(e => {
  this.form.patchValue({latitude: parseFloat(e)});
});
```

Obviously this doesn't work, it creates an infinite loop.

How can I do something like this but without the loop?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[patchValue](https://angular.io/api/forms/FormGroup) accept an secondary argument containing options, including an `emitEvent` option.

You can update your code with

```
this.form.get('latitude').valueChanges.subscribe(e => {
  this.form.patchValue({latitude: parseFloat(e)}, {emitEvent: false});
});
```

and you will avoid the infinite loop as the `patchValue` method won't trigger another `valueChanges`.